# Making a matrix of a specific structure

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe

Please note: I don't know where I am mistaking but I have spent whole day trying to solve this problem. So, I request not to discard it as duplicate question and treat this as a very specific question related to matrix structure.

I have the following data.frame:

```
dput(c.m.q)

structure(list(ASK_Price = c(1801, 1687.3, 1687.2, 1688.95, 1687.15, 
1688.95, 1687.5, 1688.85, 1689, 1688.95, 1687.5, 1688, 1688, 
1687.5, 1689.95, 1685.85, 1689.9, 1689.95, 1688.8, 1688.95, 1687.15, 
1687.2, 1690, 1688, 1688, 1690, 1688.7, 1690, 1688.7, 1689.9, 
1688.7, 1689.9, 1688.7, 1689.9, 1689.8, 1687.95, 1689.75, 1689.7, 
1687.95, 1689.35, 1689.3), BID_Price = c(1651, 1688.5, 1687, 
1688.5, 1687, 1688.5, 1687.05, 1688.5, 1687.05, 1687.05, 1688.5, 
1688.5, 1688.5, 1688.5, 1688.7, 1685.35, 1688.2, 1688.95, 1685.6, 
1685.6, 1689.05, 1685.8, 1689.1, 1686.1, 1686.25, 1689.95, 1688.05, 
1689.95, 1688.1, 1689.8, 1688.1, 1689.8, 1686.1, 1689.8, 1689.7, 
1686.15, 1689.7, 1689.15, 1686.15, 1689.15, 1689.15)), .Names = c("ASK_Price", 
"BID_Price"), row.names = c(1L, 17704L, 17707L, 17708L, 17709L, 
17710L, 17713L, 17714L, 17717L, 17720L, 17729L, 17732L, 17735L, 
17738L, 17983L, 17984L, 17985L, 17986L, 18015L, 18018L, 18029L, 
18032L, 18033L, 18223L, 18225L, 18226L, 18227L, 18228L, 18229L, 
18230L, 18231L, 18232L, 18233L, 18234L, 18235L, 18236L, 18237L, 
18238L, 18239L, 18240L, 18241L), class = "data.frame")
```

I want it to look similar to this in structure:

```
dput(mydata)

structure(c(4.56, 4.57, 4.53, 4.59, 4.55, 4.59, 4.59, 4.55, 4.55, 
4.55, 4.59, 4.55, 4.59, 4.59, 4.7, 4.64, 4.65, 4.66, 4.65, 4.66, 
4.66, 4.65, 4.65, 4.65, 4.66, 4.65, 4.66, 4.66), .Dim = c(14L, 2L))
```

I have tried the following:

```
c.m.q<-as.matrix(sapply(c.m.q, as.numeric))
```

But I don't get the similar matrix strucutre:

```
structure(c(1801, 1687.3, 1687.2, 1688.95, 1687.15, 1688.95, 
1687.5, 1688.85, 1689, 1688.95, 1687.5, 1688, 1688, 1687.5, 1689.95, 
1685.85, 1689.9, 1689.95, 1688.8, 1688.95, 1687.15, 1687.2, 1690, 
1688, 1688, 1690, 1688.7, 1690, 1688.7, 1689.9, 1688.7, 1689.9, 
1688.7, 1689.9, 1689.8, 1687.95, 1689.75, 1689.7, 1687.95, 1689.35, 
1689.3, 1651, 1688.5, 1687, 1688.5, 1687, 1688.5, 1687.05, 1688.5, 
1687.05, 1687.05, 1688.5, 1688.5, 1688.5, 1688.5, 1688.7, 1685.35, 
1688.2, 1688.95, 1685.6, 1685.6, 1689.05, 1685.8, 1689.1, 1686.1, 
1686.25, 1689.95, 1688.05, 1689.95, 1688.1, 1689.8, 1688.1, 1689.8, 
1686.1, 1689.8, 1689.7, 1686.15, 1689.7, 1689.15, 1686.15, 1689.15, 
1689.15), .Dim = c(41L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("ASK_Price", "BID_Price")))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can set the `dimnames` to NULL after converting to `matrix` (assuming from the expected output showed in the OP's post without any dimnames)

```
m1 <- `dimnames<-`(as.matrix(c.m.q), NULL)
```

If we check the `dput` of 'm1', it is of similar structure

```
dput(m1)

structure(c(1801, 1687.3, 1687.2, 1688.95, 1687.15, 1688.95, 
1687.5, 1688.85, 1689, 1688.95, 1687.5, 1688, 1688, 1687.5, 1689.95, 
1685.85, 1689.9, 1689.95, 1688.8, 1688.95, 1687.15, 1687.2, 1690, 
1688, 1688, 1690, 1688.7, 1690, 1688.7, 1689.9, 1688.7, 1689.9, 
1688.7, 1689.9, 1689.8, 1687.95, 1689.75, 1689.7, 1687.95, 1689.35, 
1689.3, 1651, 1688.5, 1687, 1688.5, 1687, 1688.5, 1687.05, 1688.5, 
1687.05, 1687.05, 1688.5, 1688.5, 1688.5, 1688.5, 1688.7, 1685.35, 
1688.2, 1688.95, 1685.6, 1685.6, 1689.05, 1685.8, 1689.1, 1686.1, 
1686.25, 1689.95, 1688.05, 1689.95, 1688.1, 1689.8, 1688.1, 1689.8, 
1686.1, 1689.8, 1689.7, 1686.15, 1689.7, 1689.15, 1686.15, 1689.15, 
1689.15), .Dim = c(41L, 2L))
```

Comment: @PolarBear Where is `n_trades` in the posted dput as I am not getting the context in the error you mentioned?

Comment: @PolarBear, you need to ask your real question, not a question about something else you think will solve your real problem for you.