# How to make a matrix without dimension names from a list

Tags: r, list, matrix

I have a list:

```
direc <- structure(list(no_trades = 3L, sell_trades = 19L, buy_trades = 18L), .Names = c("no_trades", "sell_trades", "buy_trades"))
# $no_trades
# [1] 3
# 
# $sell_trades
# [1] 19
# 
# $buy_trades
# [1] 18
```

I want to make a matrix without dimension names from this list. That would be similar to this matrix structure:

```
classified <- structure(c(9, 6, 13, 9, 6, 13, 9, 6, 13, 9, 6, 13, 9, 6, 13, 9, 6, 13, 9, 6, 13, 9, 6, 13, 9, 6, 13, 9, 6, 13, 9, 6, 13, 9, 6, 13, 9, 6, 13, 9, 6, 13, 9, 6, 13), .Dim = c(3L, 15L))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14] [,15]
# [1,]    9    9    9    9    9    9    9    9    9     9     9     9     9     9     9
# [2,]    6    6    6    6    6    6    6    6    6     6     6     6     6     6     6
# [3,]   13   13   13   13   13   13   13   13   13    13    13    13    13    13    13
```

I have tried the following code from another [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39064869/making-a-matrix-of-a-specific-structure/39064899?noredirect=1#comment65478526_39064899) meant for dataframe to matrix conversion:

```
m2 <- `dimnames<-`(as.matrix(direc), NULL)
```

But it again gives me a list:

> structure(list(3L, 19L, 18L), .Dim = c(3L, 1L))

Thanks in advance for the answer.

Comment: Perhaps you need `"dimnames<-"(do.call(cbind, direc), NULL)`

Comment: @nrussell No, Please see the code. It is not working for list. That question was asked by me in relation to dataframe to name less matrix converison.

Comment: @PolarBear In your previous case, it was a data.frame, now it is a `list` and conversion to `matrix` can be done by `cbind` the elements of the `list` and then do the `dimnames` to NULL.  If the `list` elements are of different length, you need to pad NA to adjust for length before doing the `cbind`.

Comment: it worked! although I had to use rbind instead of cbind. One query: why I am getting integer instead of numbers. int [1, 1:3] 3 19 18 instead of num [1:3, 1:15] 9 6 13 9 6 13 9 6 13 9 ....  Also please write an answer so I can accept it in appreciation of your help.

Comment: `do.call(cbind, setNames(direc, NULL))` would be my choice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the 'direc' is a `list` and conversion to `matrix` with `as.matrix` won't happen directly, but we can change it to `matrix` with `rbind/cbind`.  The initial `direc` elements are all `integer` class.  If we need to have `numeric` class, it needs to be converted

```
m1 <- `dimnames<-`(do.call(cbind, lapply(direc, as.numeric)), NULL)
dput(m1)
#structure(c(3, 19, 18), .Dim = c(1L, 3L))
```

If the `list` elements have unequal lengths, it may be better to pad with NA before doing the `cbind`

```
`dimnames<-`(do.call(cbind, lapply(direc, `length<-`, max(lengths(direc)))), NULL)
```

---

To understand why `as.matrix` did not work here, we can check the `methods` of `list`

```
methods(class = "list")
#[1] all.equal     as.data.frame as.data.table as_data_frame
#[5] coerce        escape        melt          Ops           relist       
#[10] sotrunc       within
```

It did not have the `as.matrix` option.

Comment: Kindly do the needful if you also think that this question is not duplicate.

Comment: @PolarBear  It is not closed as dupe, but i think it is related to your earlier post though it is not an exact dupe.

Comment: please see this related question that needs answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39180720/running-functions-that-require-specific-object-class-inside-for-loop Thank you