# How to deal with the object class conversion in a for loop

Tags: r, list, for-loop, matrix, dataframe

***Kindly note: Down votes do not help me but only hinder me to solve this question by reducing its visibility. And I request the SO community to comment how to improve this question in order to solve my problem.***

I have a dataframe that have multiple dates (3) for students (Amy,Bob) and I want to perform certain operations on the subsets of students and dates. Please consider answering the question through the for loop process with the object class conversion rather than giving single line code to solve this problem.I am required to run two functions inside the loop.  ***First one requires a numerical matrix with(A,B) and second one requires a list.*** The Sum and division operations are there just for illustration. Sample data:

```
dput(jj)
structure(list(month = structure(c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 
1, 2, 3), class = "Date"), student = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Amy", "Bob"), class = "factor"), 
    A = c(9, 7, 6, 8, 6, 9, 3, 2, 1, 5, 6, 5), B = c(6, 7, 8, 
    5, 6, 7, 5, 4, 6, 3, 1, 5)), .Names = c("month", "student", 
"A", "B"), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = "data.frame")
```

#necessary denotes the step assumed to be compulsary due to object class requirements. This is the code:

```
   dong<-data.frame()
IDs<-unique(jj$student)
uniq <- unique(jj$month)
king<-list() #necessary

for (i in IDs ){ 
  for (j in uniq){
  tmp <- jj[jj$student==IDs[i]& jj$month==uniq[j],] 
  tmp$month<-NULL
  tmp$student<-NULL
  tmp1 <- `dimnames<-`(as.matrix(tmp), NULL) #necessary
  #storing column sums as list element

  king[[1]][1]<- sum(tmp1[,1])
  king[[1]][2]<- sum(tmp1[,2])


  kong <- `dimnames<-`(do.call(cbind, lapply(king, as.numeric)), NULL) #necessary
  #dividing column sums
  bong<- kong[,1]/kong[,2]
  dong<-rbind(dong,c(i,j,bong))

}}
```

but I am getting

```
Error in `*tmp*`[[1]] : subscript out of bounds
```

I am also confused how to save my operation result bong for each student and month subset in a single dataframe. 
The output should look like:

```
 #       month student         Bong
    #1 1970-01-02     Amy 1.5454545
    #2 1970-01-03     Amy 1.0000000
    #3 1970-01-04     Amy 1.0000000
    #4 1970-01-02     Bob 1.0000000
    #5 1970-01-03     Bob 1.6000000
    #6 1970-01-04     Bob 0.5454545
```

Thank you

Comment: what is your intended output? it's not entirely clear what you're trying to do from the code

Answer (score 1):

An immediate problem is that there's no variable named `1` in `tmp1`, so you're trying to sum a nonexistent variable. Your line

```
tmp1 <- `dimnames<-`(as.matrix(tmp), NULL) #necessary
```

strips the dimension names of the matrix, so they get reset to the default values for R variables (V1, V2, ...).

Additionally, matrices require all elements to be the same type. Since you have character columns, all columns will be converted to character format, and your sums won't work without coercing back to numeric.

Comment: Please check now. I have edited the code. And +1 for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option:

```
x <- by(jj, list(jj$month, jj$student), with, sum(A) / sum(B))
y <- as.table(x)
names(dimnames(y)) <- c('month', 'student')
```

The result in the form of a contingency table

```
y
#            student
#month              Amy       Bob
#  1970-01-02 1.5454545 1.0000000
#  1970-01-03 1.0000000 1.6000000
#  1970-01-04 1.0000000 0.5454545
```

or as a data-frame

```
as.data.frame.table(y, responseName='C')
#       month student         C
#1 1970-01-02     Amy 1.5454545
#2 1970-01-03     Amy 1.0000000
#3 1970-01-04     Amy 1.0000000
#4 1970-01-02     Bob 1.0000000
#5 1970-01-03     Bob 1.6000000
#6 1970-01-04     Bob 0.5454545
```

Comment: The dataframe output you show is exactly that I need.  Actually I am required to run two functions inside the loop. First one requires a numerical matrix with(A,B) and second one requires a list. bong<- kong$V1/kong$V2 was meant to illustrate that I need to call list elements for my second functions inside my loop.

Comment: The column `C` is the result of `sum(A) / sum(B)` in the first line. You can replace that with a more complicated expression if you need, as long as it only involves the variables `A` and `B`.

Comment: You are not getting what I want. I am required to run two functions inside the loop. First one requires a numerical matrix with(A,B) and second one requires a list.

Comment: @PolarBear Yes I don't get it.

Comment: Please follow the process I have shown in the question. It Must use two functions one requires numerical matrix and the other list before arriving at the answer.