# Group Data By Trip in R

Tags: r, timestamp

I have data in the following format:

```
   DeviceId               VIN Latitude Longitude            TrueTime
1 S5353532523              XY1  37.51874 -87.47483 2016-06-05 18:46:00
2 S5353532523              XY1  37.52975 -87.47588 2016-06-05 18:46:00
3 S5353532523              XY1  37.53472 -87.47734 2016-06-05 18:47:00
4 S5353532523              XY1  37.53769 -87.47846 2016-06-05 18:47:00
5 S5353532523              XY1  37.54271 -87.47963 2016-06-05 18:47:00
6 S5353532523              XY1  37.54780 -87.47942 2016-06-05 18:47:00
...
```

I want to group this data into trips. Using dplyr I start with:

```
 Data %>% group_by(VIN, DeviceID) %>% ?
```

However I'm curious what I should put in the question mark. Essentially I want to add a column that assigns a tripID from 1 onwards after the previous time increment is larger than 5 minutes.

So at some point, when the TrueTime changes by more than 5 minutes, the tripCounter goes up by 1. Also, it needs to increment over VINs and DeviceID as well (so the counter shouldn't reset to 1 at the start of each group).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `difftime` to get the difference between the adjacent elements of each group, specify the `units` as `"mins"`, create a logical index, `cumsum` to create the 'TripID'

```
Data %>% 
      group_by(VIN, DeviceId) %>% 
      mutate(TripID = cumsum(c(TRUE, difftime(TrueTime[-1], 
                             TrueTime[-n()], units = "mins")>5)))
```

It is not clear about the resetting part.  If this is based on 'TrueTime' greater than 5 min across the groups, we don't need the `group_by`

```
Data %>%
       mutate(TripID = cumsum(c(TRUE, difftime(TrueTime[-1], 
                     TrueTime[-nrow(Data)], units = "mins")>5)))
```

Or if it needs to add after doing the `group_by`

```
Data %>% 
     group_by(VIN, DeviceId) %>%
     mutate(TripID = cumsum(c(TRUE, difftime(TrueTime[-1], 
              TrueTime[-n()], units = "mins")>5))) %>%
     ungroup() %>% 
     mutate(TripID = group_indices_(., .dots = c("VIN", "DeviceId"))-1 + TripID)
```

NOTE: The 'TrueTime' class assumed is `POSIXct`

#### data

```
Data <- structure(list(DeviceId = c("S5353532523", "S5353532523", "S5353532523", 
"S5353532523", "S5353532523", "S5353532523", "S5353532523", "S5353532523", 
"S5353532523", "S5353532523", "S5353532523", "S5353532523"), 
VIN = c("XY1", "XY1", "XY1", "XY1", "XY1", "XY1", "XY2", 
"XY2", "XY2", "XY2", "XY2", "XY2"), Latitude = c(37.51874, 
37.52975, 37.53472, 37.53769, 37.54271, 37.5478, 37.51874, 
37.52975, 37.53472, 37.53769, 37.54271, 37.5478), Longitude = c(-87.47483, 
-87.47588, -87.47734, -87.47846, -87.47963, -87.47942, -87.47483, 
-87.47588, -87.47734, -87.47846, -87.47963, -87.47942), TrueTime = structure(c(1465132560, 
1465132560, 1465132620, 1465132620, 1465133040, 1465133040, 
1465132560, 1465132560, 1465133100, 1465133160, 1465133160, 
1465133160), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "")), .Names = c("DeviceId", 
"VIN", "Latitude", "Longitude", "TrueTime"), row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: please see if you can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39180720/how-to-deal-with-the-object-class-conversion-in-a-for-loop-necessary-for-finasym

Comment: I'm getting a "TrueTime" has an unsupported type: POSIXlt, POSIXt? Not sure why as I've converted it using "as.Posixlt"

Comment: @user1357015  the `dplyr` mutate supports only `POSIXct`, please convert it using `as.POSIXct`

Comment: @akrun: That's fixed but now I'm getting: 

`Error: incompatible size (990), expecting 989 (the group size) or 1
In addition: Warning message:
In unclass(time1) - unclass(time2) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length`

I've added a filter(n()>1) to make sure that each group has at least two entries

Comment: @user1357015 I appended a `TRUE` at the beginning i.e. `c(TRUE, ..)` to make sure that the lengths are the same.  I also created few more rows to test it and it is working here.

Comment: @akrun: Hmm, not sure how to fix without sharing original data -- which I can't. Seems like somewhere the differences aren't getting counted

Comment: @user1357015  I fixed it.  THanks for notifying me. Had a bug i.e. `nrow(data)` changed to `n()`

Comment: @Akrun, Ah i see, you need the count within the group. Not the whole dataframe. :-) Thanks for your help!